# Why is ImmutableList<T> a class but ImmutableArray<T> a struct?

Tags: c#, immutability, design-decisions

When you read the documentation for [ImmutableArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-5.0) and [ImmutableList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-5.0), you can see that:

- `ImmutableArray<T>` has been implemented as a `struct`
- `ImmutableList<T>` has been implemented as a `class`

**Question:**

Can you explain why such design decision?

Especially, why `ImmutableArray<T>` is a `struct`.

After all, `System.Array` is a `class` so, why it isn't the case for `ImmutableArray<T>`?

Comment: From this post it sounds like the reason was for performance: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article sheds a bit of light on the decision to make .Net ImmutableArray a "struct" instead of a class:

> [**Choosing Between Class and Struct**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)
>
> ✔️ CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the
> type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
> other objects.
>
> ❌ AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following
> characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.
>
> In all other cases, you should define your types as classes.

**See also**:

- [Array covariance: not just ugly, but slow too | Jon Skeet's coding blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too/)
- [Please welcome ImmutableArray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/)

Comment: Could the same argument be made for `ImmutableList`?